# How can I quickly zoom in on the Mac OS X version of Word without having to use the menu?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, zoom

(I'm using the Mac version MS Word 2011)

I used to happily use the wheel mouse to zoom but, after upgrading to the Mac Magic mouse (using only finger slide movement to scroll and pan) I can no longer hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and roll the mouse to zoom (driving me crazy) and I can't see a useful keyboard shortcut and the zoom slider bar in the lower right of the Word screen isn't practical (in my experience). Is there any way to zoom in on the Mac Version of Microsoft Word 2011 without resorting to using a menu?

Comment: Get a clue microsoft. Glad this question is being asked. Unhappy it _needs_ to be.

Answer (score 33):

Try <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+scroll. (This works on the touchpad in a MacBook Pro. I don't have a Magic Mouse.)

Answer (score 12):

there is no pre-defined method for doing this via the keyboard but you can set one up

1. Say within Word 2008, go to Tools --> Customize Keyboard...
2. Select the category 'View' on the left
3. In the 'commands' list, look for ViewZoomIn. Select it.
4. Place your cursor in the textbox next to 'Press new keyboard shortcut.
5. Press a combination of keys (i.e. your chosen shortcut. I chose Command+Option+.)
6. Make sure in the 'Current keys' box that you are not overwriting something important)
7. If you're happy with the shortcut, click on 'Assign'
8. Repeat the same operation for ViewZoomOut. I chose Command+Option+,)

i used command = and command -

Comment: Yeeehaaa McGrailm - MANY thanks - this was the answer I was hoping for ... PS. I followed your path, it worked for me first time, I exited and reloaded WORD, it stuck. I'm happy.  Thank you.  Thanks also Mohan and Daniel ... I hope the surf's up for y'all (or whatever your passion is). HB

Comment: Your welcome, glad I could help my sight isn't the greatest so it helps to know these kinds of things. Don't forget to accept an answer 8 > )

Comment: this also works for Office 2015, thank you!

Comment: Works on Office 2016

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any of that. Go to System Preferences on a Mac. Go to  Accessibility. Go to the Zoom tab. Go the tic box for **Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom:** choose **control** on the drop down menu and you get your old favorite feature back. Now when you hold down control and use the scroll wheel you will be zooming in and out magnification-wise with your monitor. Easy!

Comment: Usable as a last resort, but this definitely does not do what the OP wanted, which is the regular Word zooming, where only the page’s content is being magnified.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom out and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in.

You don’t need to set any macros up. This works for everyone.

Comment: In Office 2016 these shortcuts no longer works.

Comment: Except MS products with an original point of view.

Comment: This is not the case. You need to set it up like @mcgrailm's answer.

Comment: in Office 2016 these shortcuts apply on changing the font size. Just use ctrl + move up/down on the mouse or trackpad